# Change keyboard language using desktop icon

Tags: raspbian, keyboard, desktop

I need a way for call agents to be able to change keyboard layout to the language they need via dedicated desktop shortcut icons. E.g. Chinese agent double-clicks icon "chinese language" and he gets it, Ukrainian agent double-clicks "ukrainian language" etc. so that everybody gets their special language characters.

I tried running a script which rewrites /etc/default/keyboard e.g. from "us" to "gb" keyboard and seemed to work. But found out only root can do that and call agents should not be sudoers.

I was looking for a script to bring up **Keyboard layout** window, that would be a nice way as well, agents could then just scroll, find their language and change it easily.

I googled intensively and couldn't find anything real. Does anybody have experience with this? Thanks!

Comment: You may want to check out `localectl` ... `man localectl` ... [localectl man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/localectl.1.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a great solution.

**Right-click** bottom bar => **Add / Remove Panel Items** => **Add** => **Keyboard Layout Handler**

I can then easily change keyboard layout by clicking the flag appearing in bottom bar.